# Java Code for Searching Particular Topic's comment in Youtube

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api

I am searching particular topic's comment. Topic :- TCS

**Here My Full Code:-**

```
package com.video.youtube;

import java.net.URL;
import com.google.gdata.client.youtube.YouTubeQuery;

public class Y_Ex {

  YouTubeQuery query = new YouTubeQuery(new URL("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos"));

  query.setOrderBy(YouTubeQuery.OrderBy.VIEW_COUNT);
  query.setFullTextQuery("TCS");
  query.setSafeSearch(YouTubeQuery.SafeSearch.NONE);
  VideoFeed videoFeed = service.query(query, VideoFeed.class);
  printVideoFeed(videoFeed, true);

}
```

**I also added this jar files :-**

gdata-client-1.0.jar

gdata-youtube-2.0.jar

gdata-media-1.0.jar

gdata-cor-1.0.jar

**But error occurred :-**

Return type for method is missing

Service cannot be resolved...

**This is screen-shot.**

[image]

**So please help me to solve this error.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of code:

```
YouTubeQuery query = new YouTubeQuery(new 
    URL("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos"));
query.setOrderBy(YouTubeQuery.OrderBy.VIEW_COUNT);
query.setFullTextQuery("TCS");
query.setSafeSearch(YouTubeQuery.SafeSearch.NONE);
VideoFeed videoFeed = service.query(query, VideoFeed.class);
printVideoFeed(videoFeed, true);
```

should be inside a method rather than being immediately inside the class.

As pointed out by stepanian there are other programmatic errors in your code, for example:

1. The object `service` is being used but never instantiated.
2. The method `printVideoFeed` isn't defined by your class yet getting invoked.

Comment: This would still give an error with service object not being instantiated.

Comment: And no printVideoFeed method is declared.

Comment: I added method printVideoFeed... but still error occurred in service method

Comment: You have to instantiate the service object. Something like YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService("test");

Answer (score 2):

You have not instantiated the service object among MANY other things. I suggest this site for your reading pleasure:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial